# Javascript onkeyup delayed function call

Tags: javascript, events, timer, dom-events

I want to make a Javascript function that fires `onkeyup` event and its task is to call a main resolver function but only if no keys are fired for at least x milliseconds where `x` is the functions parameter.

For instance:

We have html code:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="suggestion" onkeyup="callMe(200);"/>
</body>
```

and Javascript something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callMe(ms)
    {
        //wait at least x ms then call main logic function
        // e.g. doMain();
        alert("I've been called after timeout"); //for testing purposes
    }
</script>
```

So while I'm typing the alert won't be called until you don't type anything for at least x ms.

Comment: You can't "wait" in Javascript, but you could use a global variable to store a timeout (created with `setTimeout`). When each `keyup` event occurs, clear (if present) the existing timeout and set the next one. What have you already tried? Where's your code?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a timer, you also need to clear the previous timer each time.

To achieve this, better use "wrapper" function:

```
<input type="text" id="suggestion" onkeyup="DelayedCallMe(200);"/>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var _timer = 0;
function DelayedCallMe(num) {
    if (_timer)
        window.clearTimeout(_timer);
    _timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callMe(num);
    }, 500);
}
```

This will execute the function 500 milliseconds after the last key up event.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/5FPtz/).

Comment: This doesn't help at all. Like i've said, the function execution need to be only once after x ms. Not every time you have the keyup event.

Comment: Ok this will do it.
<code>var _timer = 0;
   function DelayedCallMe(ms) {
    if (_timer)
     window.clearTimeout(_timer);
     _timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
     callMe();
    }, ms);
   }
   
   function callMe()
   {
    alert("haha");
   }

Comment: @ZeDonDino cheers, if the number is the delay amount, just replace 500 with `num`.

Comment: Whatever, I'm a noob and cant even post code to comments. But thanks mate for your help

Comment: What code you want to post? You can edit your question with more code if you want and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="suggestion" onkeyup="callMe(200);"/>
<script>
    var to;
    function callMe(ms) {
       clearTimeout(to);
       to = setTimeout(function(){
           alert("I've been called after timeout");
       }, ms);
    }
</script>

​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q3Jk/1)

Comment: nicely done. Worked for me!