# Jquery autocomplete:Load the source just once

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying a jquery autocomplete but I want the source to be loaded just once.
I do not want to call ajax action class every time I type a letter. I also do not want to use cache as it is browser level cache. So Basically what I need it want to load my list just once and use autocomplete on it. Is this possible? Any ideas would be really helpful..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay the call.
See:
[Javascript onkeyup delayed function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910844/javascript-onkeyup-delayed-function-call)

```
var _timer = 0;
function DelayedCallMe(num) {
    if (_timer)
        window.clearTimeout(_timer);
    _timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callMe(num);
    }, 500);
}
```

Then call the function in onkeyup :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="DelayedCallMe(200);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one ajax call and build autocomplete on success :

```js
$.getJSON({
    url: 'remote_url/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: data,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          console.log(suggestion)
        }
      });
    },
    error: function (res) {
      console.log(res)
    }
  });
```